# Change Text Color in ExpandedListView, when list is expanded

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a expandedlistview and I want to change the textcolor of group when the particular group is expanded. I tried many things but not able to find solution.Please let me know if there is any solution for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the adapter you're using you should be overriding the `getGroupView()` method.  One of the parameters you get is an `isExpanded` boolean value.  Just use that value to decide what color to set the textview in question.  Here is an example:

```
@Override
public void getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Here you would do your convertView initialization
    // ...
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    if(isExpanded)
        textView.setTextColor(/* some color */);
    else
        textView.setTextColor(/* some other color */);
    // Do the rest of your view binding
    //...
}
```

Comment: I know that textView.setTextColor(/* some other color */); is the solution, but that does not worked for me. I don't understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code :

```
@Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View parentView = ( View )convertView.findViewById( R.id.settings_menu );
            parentView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.background1 );

            TextView parentTextView = ( TextView )convertView.findViewById( R.id.menu_title );
            parentTextView.setText( groups[ groupPosition ].toString() );

            if( isExpanded ){
                convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.settings_background2 );
                parentTextView.setTextColor( R.color.black);
            }

            return convertView ;
        }
```